# User Specific Orchard Localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

In my project, I have implemented localization & implemented it with the localization module of the orchard with PO files but now i want to implement localization to the user specific so how to implement it in Orchard.

Comment: I'm trying to use RM.Localization as well Culture Picker modules for that but both are not supported in Orchard 1.8.1.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you clarify what exactly you want to implement?

Comment: is there any way for set user-wise language means set specific culture for the particular user. E.g. : for John culture should be en-US and for james it should be nl-NL

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box Orchard supports only setting a culture globally for the whole site. However, it should be possible to override this culture by implementing the `ICultureSelector` interface in your custom Orchard module.

Take a look at the `Orchard.Localization.Services.SiteCultureSelector` implementation - it retrieves the culture stored in the current site. You can add a similar implementation which retrieves the culture from the current user profile and give it a higher priority. This should override the site culture.